# How to show that the following relation is valid for nested summation?

Tags: summation, summation-method, summation-by-parts

I have seen following relation in a research paper $$\sum_{x_1=1,x_1\neq1}^{K}~\sum_{x_2=x_1+1,x_2\neq 1}^K\cdots \sum_{x_n=x_{n-1}+1,x_n\neq1}^Kf(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)+\sum_{x_1=1,x_1\neq2}^{K}~\sum_{x_2=x_1+1,x_2\neq 2}^K\cdots \sum_{x_n=x_{n-1}+1,x_n\neq2}^Kf(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)+\cdots \sum_{x_1=1,x_1\neq K}^{K}~\sum_{x_2=x_1+1,x_2\neq K}^K\cdots \sum_{x_n=x_{n-1}+1,x_n\neq K}^Kf(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=(K-n)\sum_{x_1=1}^{K}~\sum_{x_2=x_1+1}^K\cdots \sum_{x_n=x_{n-1}+1}f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n).$$ Where $K$ and $n$ are some positive constants. I do not know how to prove that the left hand side is equal to the right hand side. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We transform the left-hand side into a somewhat more convenient representation. This way we can better see why the equality is valid.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{{x_1=1}\atop{x_1\ne 1}}^K&\sum_{{x_2=x_1+1}\atop{x_2\ne 1}}^K\cdots\sum_{{x_n=x_{n-1}+1}\atop{x_n\ne 1}}^Kf(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\\
> &\qquad+\sum_{{x_1=1}\atop{x_1\ne 2}}^K\sum_{{x_2=x_1+1}\atop{x_2\ne 2}}^K\cdots\sum_{{x_n=x_{n-1}+1}\atop{x_n\ne 2}}^Kf(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\\
> &\qquad\,\,\vdots\\
> &\qquad+\sum_{{x_1=1}\atop{x_1\ne K}}^K\sum_{{x_2=x_1+1}\atop{x_2\ne K}}^K\cdots\sum_{{x_n=x_{n-1}+1}\atop{x_n\ne K}}^Kf(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\\
> &=\sum_{{1\leq x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n\leq K}\atop{x_j\ne 1, 1\leq j\leq n}}f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)
> +\sum_{{1\leq x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n\leq K}\atop{x_j\ne 2, 1\leq j\leq n}}f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\\
> &\qquad+\cdots+\sum_{{1\leq x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n\leq K}\atop{x_j\ne K, 1\leq j\leq n}}f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\\
> &=\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^K\sum_{{1\leq x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n\leq K}\atop{x_j\ne k, 1\leq j\leq n}}f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)}\tag{1}\\
> &\;\color{blue}{=(K-n)\sum_{1\leq x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n\leq K}f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)}\tag{2}\\
> &=(K-n)\sum_{x_1=1}^K\sum_{x_2=x_1+1}^K\cdots\sum_{x_n=x_{n-1}+1}^Kf(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)
> \end{align*}

The crucial part is the step from (1) to (2). Let us consider in (2) a specific valid $n$-tupel $x^0=(x_1^0,x_2^0,\ldots,x_n^0)$ with $1\leq x_1^0<x_2^0<\cdots <x_n^0\leq K$ and ask how often it occurs in (1).

Since the first component in $x^0$ is $x_1^0$, the index $k=x_1^0$ is to exclude. Since the second component in $x^0$ is $x_2^0$, the index $k=x_2^0$ is to exclude. Continuing this way, we have to sum over $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,K\}\setminus\{x_1^0,x_2^0,\ldots,x_n^0\}$ in (1) and since $x_1^0<x_2^0<\cdots<x_n^0$ are $n$ different values, the $n$-tupel $x^0$ occurs precisely in $K-n$ inner sums of (1).

This holds for each $n$-tupel occurring in (2), so that the factor $K-n$ is justified.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: @FrankMoses: You're welcome.